# Conditional based on character following the macro

Tags: macros, conditionals, unicode

Basically, I would like to something like `\xspace` does, i.e. the meaning of the macro should depend on what is following it. So for example if I say

```
\mymacro a
```

it might expand to `foo`, and if any other character is following, it should expand to `bar`. In my specific case I'll try to match a unicode character, if that makes a difference.

**Edit:** Specifically, I want to influence the spacing after an integral. When it stands alone, the default spacing is fine. If it is the first of multiple integrals, the space became too wide. Here is what I cobbled together from the previous answer:

```
\newcommand\timeintegral[1]{
    ∫_{t_0}^{t_1} \if ∫#1 \!\!\! \fi #1
}
```

This is how it looks in use:

```
\timeintegral E \, dt = \timeintegral ∫_z ∫_φ f \, dφ dz dt
```

[image]

Comment: How to manage Unicode characters depends on what engine you're using; with `pdflatex` it's different than with `xelatex` or `lualatex`. Knowledge of the character is needed; also a “real world” use case would be nice.

Comment: The previous answer (now deleted?) worked for me, so I'm good. I can still add the wanted information if you think this may be useful for someone else.

Comment: I'm not really sure it worked, if you're using `pdflatex` and tested for a Unicode character beyond the ASCII block.

Comment: I'm using LuaLaTeX, and it works for what I wanted it to do. I'll add my usecase to the question.

Comment: LuaLaTeX was the missing information! But, please, go ahead and show the use case.

Comment: @Psirus I undeleted my answer, however, it may not work for the case of unicode tests, since unicode chars are made of more than one byte, while `\if` is only going to test a byte.  There are other tests that could capture it, I'm sure, but I'm not too keen on unicode testing.  If the answer works for you, I'll leave it.  If not, or if someone gives a better answer, I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a straightforward application of `\@ifnextchar`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\timeintegral}{%
   ∫_{t_0}^{t_1} \@ifnextchar∫{\!\!\!}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\timeintegral E \, dt = \timeintegral ∫_z ∫_φ f \,dφ\,dz\,dt
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The LaTeX3 version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\timeintegral}{}
 {
  ∫\sb{t\sb{0}}^{t\sb{1}} \psirus_check_int:
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \psirus_check_int:
 {
  \peek_charcode_ignore_spaces:NT ∫ { \!\!\! }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\[
\timeintegral E \, dt = \timeintegral ∫_z ∫_φ f \,dφ\,dz\,dt
\]
\end{document}
```